# 401 response when reading tweets

Tags: java, blackberry, twitter

I'm new to mobile apps development. I'm developing a blackberry application which reads tweets from the user's timeline. So far I managed to get the OAuth access token. The problem happens when I try to use this access token to read the tweets I get a 401 response with a message "Unauthorized". I'm not using any libraries I'm doing everything on my own. Could anyone help me with this?

Thanks,

Here's the code:

```
            HttpConnectionFactory factory = new HttpConnectionFactory( url,   
                HttpConnectionFactory.TRANSPORT_WIFI |
                HttpConnectionFactory.TRANSPORT_WAP2 |
                HttpConnectionFactory.TRANSPORT_BIS |
                HttpConnectionFactory.TRANSPORT_BES |
                HttpConnectionFactory.TRANSPORT_DIRECT_TCP);

        httpConn = factory.getNextConnection();
        httpConn.setRequestMethod(HttpProtocolConstants.HTTP_METHOD_GET);
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("WWW-Authenticate","OAuth realm=http://twitter.com/");
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(header.getBytes().length));
        os = httpConn.openOutputStream();

        os.write(header.getBytes());
        os.close();
        os = null;


        input = httpConn.openDataInputStream();
        int resp = httpConn.getResponseCode();

     //   Dialog.alert(httpConn.getDate()+" : "+System.currentTimeMillis());


        if (resp == HttpConnection.HTTP_OK) {

            XMLReader parser;
            try {
                parser = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();
                parser.setContentHandler(this);
                parser.parse(new InputSource(input));
                for(int i=0 ; i<2 ; i++)
                {
                    tweets.addElement( parser.getProperty("text").toString());
                    Dialog.alert(parser.getProperty("text").toString());
                }

            } catch (SAXException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Dialog.alert("your tweet was posted successfully :)");
        }
        Dialog.alert(httpConn.getResponseCode()+": "+httpConn.getResponseMessage());
        return (httpConn.getResponseCode()+": "+httpConn.getResponseMessage()); 
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return "exception";
    } catch (NoMoreTransportsException nc) {
        return "noConnection";
    } finally {
        try {
            httpConn.close();
            input.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you try using a lib? It would greatly simplify your work. I used this one on my BB app http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html

Comment: Also, where are you setting the access token for the request? Normally in a web app you'd set the token and token secret as a cookie to be able to do the requests, not sure how you'd do it when making the http call from Java.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in OAuth, however just a note:

This:

```
httpConn.setRequestMethod(HttpProtocolConstants.HTTP_METHOD_GET);
```

and this:

```
httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

are mutually exclusive things. You are posting data to server, so it should be a POST (not GET).